# python threading.Timer: do i need to protect the variable accessed inside the callback?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, thread-safety

I am trying to use threading.Timer, I am wondering is this timer is started in another thread? So I need to protect the variables accessed by this timer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could see in the [threading.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/threading.py?view=markup) file that [`threading.Timer()`](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#threading.Timer) returns an instance of a new `Thread`. Or you could run an example:

```
import threading

def ontimer():
    print threading.current_thread()

def main():
    threading.Timer(2, ontimer).start()
    print threading.current_thread()

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

You need to protect the variables accessed by `Timer`'s callback.